# Expectations on real interest rates in China

Tags: interest-rates, inflation, china

How do market practitioners approach expectations of real interest rates in China?
For the US we would look at inflation-linked bonds and surveys, but what about China?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't look at surveys for China? If I look at ECFC on Bloomberg, I see forecasts out to 2023-Q4 for both CPI and the 10y rate.

Comment: If people in the Chinese market manage their expectations of real IR with surveys, that's ok, I would like to hear about these surveys. But if there's any financial instrument that prices in that expectation, I would like to learn about it as well.